# How to turn [1, 2, 3] to 1 2 3 string in Python?

Tags: python, string, list

Need quick help but how do I turn an array of [1, 2, 3] to a string 1 2 3 in Python?

Comment: If your `list` is always 3 elements you can just do this: `'{} {} {}'.format(1,2,3)` or `'{} {} {}'.format(*nums)`

Answer (score 7):

The following generator expression `' '.join(str(i) for i in [1,2,3])` will transform each number in the list into a space-separated string `'1 2 3'`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
' '.join(map(str, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Or this:

```
' '.join(str(x) for x in [1, 2, 3])
```

This one works, too. It's not efficient and kinda ugly, but shows how to solve the problem using a completely different approach - namely, regular expressions.

```
import re
re.sub(r'[],\[]', '', str([1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: I would +1 this if you remove the ugly `regex` solution :D

Comment: @jamylak how about now? I didn't remove it, but added a warning about ugliness :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3]
>>> ' '.join('%u' % x for x in L)
'1 2 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me, whether you want to turn `[1,2,3]` into `'123'` or `'1 2 3'`.

```
' '.join(str(i) for i in [1,2,3])
```

will result in '1 2 3'

and

```
''.join(str(i) for i in [1,2,3])
```

will result in '123'

(Note difference between ''.join and ' '.join.)

Answer (score -4):

go over the array and append each element to a string, start with an empty string.

Comment: This is not the preferred way in Python. Also, the `join` method is much faster.

Comment: Not just that, but this is a trap. This won't perform too badly in CPython, but in other implementations this could kill performance.